# Проектировка архитектуры сайта

Tags: php, html, cms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь ресурсы с уроками по построению самой архитектуры сайта, желательно с примерами. Все ресурсы, которые я находил, дают либо слишком обобщённое представление об этой теме (например, что такое MVC, без описания, как  M, V и C связаны между собой), либо освещали какие-то частные случаи и их решения.
К примеру у меня есть работающий сайт-визитка небольшого магазина и тестовая версия нового варианта([omiksagro.com/test/](http://omiksagro.com/test/)), который просто представляет собой прайс товаров с их описанием и картинками, которые берутся из базы данных MySQL. Фалы сайта расположены так:

```
КОРЕНЬ
--CONTENT       -содержит контент, который инклудится в зависимости от выбранного пункта меню
----about.php
----announce.php
----announce_ajax.php
----blog.php
----contacts.php
----products_groups.php
----products.php 
--IMAGES
--SCRIPTS
----jquery.js
--CSS        -содержит стили основного окна и стили страниц контента
----content.css
----main.css
--index.php
--main.php     -содержит основную разметку страницы, хэдер, футер, меню
```

Я решил сменить дизайн, добавить мобильную версию, добавить функционала. Понимаю, что такая архитектура не очень подходит для этого. Как организовать систему, чтобы её можно было легко расширять и сопровождать другим людям?

Comment: Это действительно слишком большой вопрос. Вот если бы вы начали что-то проектировать, то участники сообщества могли бы что-то посоветовать, предостеречь от ошибок. А так, вы спрашиваете, как построить коттедж, если сейчас есть сарай.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov Мне б хотя бы брошюрку, как фундамент для коттеджа построить :) Ну вот какая есть общая практика написания фалов стилей, всё пихать в один файл или разбивать его на стили для отдельных групп компонентов? Какие обычно создают папки и по какому принципу разделяют файлы? Стараться разделять html и php или нормально, чтобы они шли вперемешку? Т.е. с чего начать? Может кто посоветует взять какое-то готовое решение за образец?

Answer (score 2):

используйте **фреймворки**, они для этого и созданы.

Советовать конкретный не буду, выберете сами какой вам кажется лучше.

Comment: Хотелось сначала обойтись без них, для самообразования и пока "подопытный" не слишком сложный.

Comment: @АртёмСвистула я могу лишь отметить что всякие паттерны и прочие архитектурные решения можно лишь условно визуализировать и понять их принцип, реализует каждый сам как знает и понимает. У каждого MVC фреймворка своя индивидуальная реализация.